# Images are not refreshed on UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have some images in my windows phone XAML page and I am setting their source from code-behind dynamically as per logic this way.

```
 img1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("/Images/MAP/" + Path + ".png");
```

and it works fine when page loads and Images loaded perfectly but as per my app logic I show a message box that is XNA based custom message box with two button. And once user click on OK I have to load images again dynamically and I was calling The same above function but at that time its give me an exception `"Invalid Cross Thread Exception"` Might be this is due to Image source setting on background thread not on UI thread so I tried `Dispatcher` as well like this

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(delegate()
                {
                    img1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("/Images/MAP/" + Path + ".png");
                }));
```

With this dispatcher there was no exception but `UI` is not refreshed

Can please anyone tell why this is so? And I tried to navigate as well on on same Message Box OK button again I am getting same "`Invalid Cross Thread`" exception

Comment: The `"Invalid Cross Thread Exception"` is indeed a problem with trying to set UI properties (`img1.Source`) or trying to do any other kind of UI action from a thread that is not the UI thread. Using the `Dispatcher` is the correct way to send code to be executed on the UI thread (this would also be the way to kick off the navigation). As for the image failed, try to hook the `ImageFailed` event like below.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an event handler to img1.ImageFailed, if an image fails to load it will do so silently unless you're listening for that event.